# Angular 2 No provider error

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating simple starter app to play with angular 2 and i am trying to make a todo service and inject him to my component and i get this error:

***No provider for TodoService! (TodoList -> TodoService)***

TodoService.ts

```
export class TodoService {
 todos: Array<Object>
 constructor() {
   this.todos = [];
 }
}
```

app.ts

```
/// <reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />

import {Component, View, bootstrap, For, If} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {TodoService} from './TodoService'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
})

@View({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  directives: [For, If],
  injectables: [TodoService]
})

class TodoList {
 todos: Array<Object>
  constructor(t: TodoService) {
    this.todos = t.todos
  }

  addTodo(todo) {
    this.todos.push({
      done:false,
      todo: todo.value
    });
  }
}

bootstrap(TodoList);
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The injectables are specified on the `@Component` not on the `@View`

You have:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
})

@View({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  directives: [For, If],
  injectables: [TodoService]  // moving this line
})
```

Change it to:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  injectables: [TodoService]  // to here
})

@View({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  directives: [For, If]
})
```

This will allow DI to pick it up and inject it into your component.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am doing exactly the same thing. However, my app is crashing at the "injectables: " line. Because the TodoService hasn't loaded, it loads later.. If I declare it in the same file its fine, but if its in a separate file it comes later. How can I avoid this?

Comment: You can probably use @InjectPromise in the constructor; see angular2.src.di.annotations_impl

Comment: check this answer for newer angular http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580083/angular2-no-provider-for-nameservice

Answer (score 1):

In the latest Angular version, you have to use providers instead of injectables, for example:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [TodoService]
})
```