# Angular2 + typescript + jspm : No provider for Http ( App -> Provider -> Http )

Tags: typescript, angular, jspm

I trying migrate from Webpack to JSPM with system.js. We have simple App component. I was fallowing this article [Angular 2 Starter Setup with JSPM, SystemJS and Typescript in atom (Part 1)](http://www.mario-brendel.com/angular2-setup/2016/01/28/Angular2_Jspm_Setup_Part1/)

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Bus} from './business.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
  <p>Hello World</p>
  `,
  providers:[Bus]
})
export class App {
  constructor(private bus : Bus) { }
}
```

and simple (business) service with `Http`

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable}     from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
 export class Bus {

  constructor(private http: Http){

  }
}
```

In Webpack works fine but here with systemjs I getting this error

> EXCEPTION: No provider for Http! (App -> Bus -> Http)

I read [Angular2 no provider for NameService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580083/angular2-no-provider-for-nameservice) but they talking about Angular2 alpha and no provider in provider and we use beta@7

I also play with

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
//import {Bus} from './business.service';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from 'angular2/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
  <p>Hello World</p>
  `,
  providers:[Http]
})
export class App {
  constructor(private bus : Http) { }
}
```

but the error is even weirder

> EXCEPTION: No provider for ConnectionBackend! (App -> Http -> ConnectionBackend)

I even tryed change to angular2-beta@6. and also angular2-beta@1 Do you know what I do wrong? thank you

Using loader versions: `systemjs@0.19.23`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the `HTTP_PROVIDERS` providers when bootstrapping your application:

```
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]);
```

or if you want to specify it at your component level:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
//import {Bus} from './business.service';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <p>Hello World</p>
  `,
  providers:[HTTP_PROVIDERS] // <-----------
})
export class App {
  constructor(private bus : Http) { }
}
```

Comment: Note that this solution does not work anymore, since recent releases have removed the `HTTP_PROVIDERS` export.

Answer (score 5):

**>= RC.5**

Add `HttpModule` to imports of the `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**<= RC.5**

You need to add `HTTP_PROVIDERS` to the providers list in bootstrap

```
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
<!-- -->
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/HTTP_PROVIDERS-let.html

Comment: Note that this solution does not work anymore, since recent releases have removed the HTTP_PROVIDERS export.

Comment: Your updated solution works like a charm, thank you so much! Upvoted! This should be the accepted answer, as it shows solutions for both pre- and post-breaking versions.