# Inject angularjs service into Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic2, ng-upgrade

I'm trying to use `$log` service into an angular 2, According to what I read you need the following steps:

1. Create a module that contains the service you want to inject.
2. Call UpgradeAdapter's upgradeNg1Provider method.

So, I did the following

```
  var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);
  var $log = initInjector.get('$log');
  angular.module('Services1', [])
    .service('$log', [$log]);
  upgradeAdapter.upgradeNg1Provider('$log');
```

Then I create an angular 2 component as the following

```
    @Component({   selector: "ion-app",   template:"<p>Test</p>" })
    @Injectable()
    export class HelloIonicPage {
      message: string;
      constructor( @Inject('$log') $log) {
        this.message = "Hi";
      }
    }
```

But when I run the application it gives me the following error:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for $log!

Also, I tried to `bootstrap` using `upgradeAdapter`:

```
  upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['Services1'])
```

But that didn't work also.
Please note that  I'm using Ionic 2 framework and the above code is written inside

```
    this.platform.ready().then(() => { 
            //The code is going here
});
```

Comment: Seems like a similar question. Check this out, you may want to use bindings or providers http://stackoverflow.com/a/32298993/1403009

Comment: @NaveenAechan That answer does not appear to be helpful, as it assumes you have access to the Angular 2 provider object. UpgradeAdapter.upgradeNg1Provider does not return anything.

Comment: Just refer to 'Angular' if you are referring to Angular 2+

Answer (score 23):

You need to register service as provider. Here is how I inject angular1 $state to angular 2 application:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
       provide: '$state', 
       useFactory: ($injector: any) => $injector.get('$state'), 
       deps: ['$injector']
    }
  ]
})
```

and then in place of injection:

```
@Injectable()
export class RestService {
  constructor(@Inject('$state') $state: any) {
    $state.go('...');
  }
}
```

Comment: `$injector is undefined`

Comment: This worked for me using an AngularJS 1.4.7 service with Angular 7.2.0

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @Liovareg works much better than the official documentation. My Angular (1.5.x) service was in a JS file and it was the `@Inject` that I was missing in Angular 13 (and is different than the official docs).

Angular JS:

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module('common')
        .service('appContext', appContext);

    appContext.$inject = ['$cookies', 'moment', '$location', 'userCacheFactory', 'urlHrefCacheFactory', 'lock'];

    function appContext($cookies, moment, $location, userCacheFactory, urlHrefCacheFactory, lock) {
      ...
      function renewSession() {
        ...
      }
      ...
      return {
        renewSession: renewSession,
        ...
      };
    };
})();
```

ajs-upgraded-providers.ts (resides at the same level as app.module.ts):

```
// @ts-ignore
import { appContext } from '../../../app/common/appContext';

export function appContextServiceFactory(injector: any) { // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  return injector.get('appContext');
}

export const ajsAppContextServiceProvider: any = { // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  deps: ['$injector'],
  provide: 'appContext',
  useFactory: appContextServiceFactory
};
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { ajsAppContextServiceProvider } from './ajs-upgraded-providers';
...
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ...,
    ajsAppContextServiceProvider
  ]
})
...
```

Angular 13 (foo.service.ts):

```
...
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SessionTimeoutService {
  ...
  public constructor(
    @Inject('appContext') private ajsAppContextService: any, // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    ...
  )
  ...
  public someMethod(): void {
    this.ajsAppContextService.renewSession();
  }
  ...
}
```