# Using angularJS services in an angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have an angularJS application that I am slowly converting to angular so my plan is to have it as a hybrid application until I am completely done the conversion. I can't get my angularJS services to work in my angular services though. I am following the steps here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#making-angularjs-dependencies-injectable-to-angular

I have my javascript angularJS service:

```
"use strict";

export class DAL {
    get($q, $filter, $http, $log, IsoStringToDate, UnitConversion, $cookies, $uibModal, Utilities) {
        ... functions that do stuff ...
    }
}

(function() {

    var dal = function ($q, $filter, $http, $log, IsoStringToDate, UnitConversion, $cookies, $uibModal, Utilities) {
        var dalInst = new DAL();
        return dalInst.get($q, $filter, $http, $log, IsoStringToDate, UnitConversion, $cookies, $uibModal, Utilities);
    };

    angular
        .module('myWebApp')
        .factory('DAL', ['$q', '$filter', '$http', '$log','IsoStringToDate','UnitConversion','$cookies','$uibModal','Utilities', dal]);

}());
```

I have my ajs-upgraded-providers.ts:

```
/// <reference path="./ajs-services/index.d.ts" />
import { DAL } from '../../app/scripts/factory/dal';

export function dalServiceFactory(i: any) {
    return i.get('DAL');
}

export const dalServiceProvider = {
    provide: DAL,
    useFactory: dalServiceFactory,
    deps: ['$injector']
};
```

But when I just try to build the project with webpack I get this error:
"TS2307: Cannot find module '../../app/scripts/factory/dal'
How can I get the typescript file using my javascript module?

UPDATE: For anyone that ends up here while trying to get a hybrid app working: This approach DID NOT work when trying to use an angularJS component/service in an Angular component/service. I ended up following the advice here: [Use AngularJS (Angular1) module from Angular2 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35237319/use-angularjs-angular1-module-from-angular2-project)
and here:
[Inject angular 1 service into Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743423/inject-angular-1-service-into-angular-2)
To get my hybrid app working. Example:

Javascript inside angularJS code:

```
angular.module('myWebApp')
    .factory('testFactory', [function() {
        return {
            test: function() {
                return 'this is a test';
            }
        };
    }]);
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UpgradeAdapter } from '@angular/upgrade';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
    ],
    declarations: [],
    entryComponents: [],
    providers: [
    {
        provide: 'TestService',
        useFactory: ($injector: any) => $injector.get('testFactory'),
        deps: ['$injector']
    }]
})
export class AppModule {
    ngDoBootstrap() {}
}

//Upgrade any angularJS components we use from old project

let upgrade = new UpgradeAdapter(AppModule, null);

upgrade.upgradeNg1Provider('testFactory');
```

Angular service that uses angularJS service:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TeamService {
    constructor(@Inject('TestService') testService: any) {
        console.log('TestService: ', testService.test());
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not combine `<reference path="" />` with modules. It will cause harm. Just use `import` and `export`.

Comment: I originally did not have the reference tag but it was the exact same error with it and without it.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that it shouldn't be used. Can you verify that the module exists at the relative path?

Comment: Try with `--allowJs`

Comment: --allowJs worked! It built ok after I added that to my tsconfig.json. Thanks! If you want to put that as an answer I can mark it as the official answer.

Comment: I I'm glad that it worked thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `"allowJs": true` under the `"compilerOptions"` property of you're **tsconfig.json** file or pass `--allowJs` to `tsc` via the command line to enable TypeScript to import JavaScript dependencies that are within the scope of the current project.

Another approach is simply to rename the .**js** file to .**ts**. It is valid TypeScript, as is all JavaScript.