# Angular2 - No provider for service error

Tags: angular, typescript

Running Angular2 framework and I'm getting the mentioned above error message

> Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:2:8 caused by: **No provider for ProductService**!

Although the **service is defined in the providers array of the app.component.ts file**, which is the relevant file for the service to be referenced (see below text). The error triggers at core.umd.js file:

```
import { ProductService } from './products/product.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'pm-app',
    template: ``,
    providers:[ ProductService ] 
}) 

product.Service code:

import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { IProduct } from './product';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService
{
    getProducts(): IProduct[]
    {
        return []
    }
}
```

**product-list.component:**

```
@Component ({
    selector: 'pm-products',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'product-list.Component.html', 
    styleUrls: ['product-list.Component.css'] 
})

export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit
{
    products: IProduct[];

    constructor(private _productService: ProductService){}

    ngOnInit(): void{
         this.products = this._productService.getProducts();
    }
}
```

and the relevant code in the **product-list.component.html:**

```
<table class='table' *ngIf="products && products.length">
```

Comment: In the future please take a second to format your question and code so it is legible. I have done it for you this time.

Comment: Can you also share ProductService code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 no provider for NameService](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580083/angular2-no-provider-for-nameservice). see the later answers which are specific to the released (not alpha/beta) versions of Angular.

Comment: Igor, Thank you, will do next time.
I went over the answer in the  Angular2 no provider for NameService case before submitting my case.

Comment: @echonax  - I added the ProductService code

Comment: @GuyE ok so how do you use this service in your component? Maybe in the html?

Comment: Where do you provide `_productService` for your `ProductListComponent`? Can you also provide AppComponent and it's html?

Comment: @echonax: See above: the products property is being initiate by the service, in the ngOnInit() function of the ProductListComponent

Comment: @GuyE ok where do you provide the service to this component?

Comment: @echonax- I'm not sure I understand your question  - the service is being injected into the constructor of the product-list.component, and the service  is calling the getProducts() method, when the component is being initiated (ngOnInit)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the provider ProductService in the app.module.ts ofcourse with importing

Comment: There's no need to provide it in a module if it is provided in the component annotation

Comment: @echonax is right and this is the case - it is imported in the component module