# No provider for function (){}! in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-providers

I am running the following command for prod build

```
ng serve --prod --env=qa
```

after running this command i don't get any errors but once i run `localhost:4200/` in the browser I get the following error

```
Uncaught Error: No provider for function (){}!
at b (core.es5.js:1169)
at core.es5.js:1207
at e._throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2649)
at e._getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2688)
at e._getByKey (core.es5.js:2620)
at e.get (core.es5.js:2489)
at dt (core.es5.js:9492)
at core.es5.js:9529
at pt (core.es5.js:9503)
at core.es5.js:9456
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580083/angular-no-provider-for-nameservice

Comment: that solution didn't help me@RameshRajendran

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar exception with this code block inside my app.module.ts

```
providers: [
  ...
  CacheService,
  {
    provide: HttpCaching,
    useFactory: httpFactory, 
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, CacheService]
  }
]
...
export function httpFactory(xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions, cacheService: CacheService): Http {
  return new HttpCaching(xhrBackend, requestOptions, cacheService);
}
```

It works great in development mode, but the injection of my CacheService fails when running it in production mode giving the **Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for function (){}!**

Please let me know why we are getting this error.

Comment: actually I was using angular-2 logger after removing that library everything worked well for me

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but I had the same error and fixed it with this script (after npm install)

```
"npm-cleanup" : "rimraf ./node_modules/PACKAGE_WITH_ANGULAR_MODULES/node_modules"
```

in my package.json, by removing the node_modules of all packages with conflicting Angular versions.

Maybe it helps someone who is still struggling with this kind of error.