# Angular HTTP Error while trying to obtain IP address from api.ipify.org

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular. I'm trying to obtain the Client's IP Address using api.ipify.org API. I'm getting error with the below shown code. Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this issue.

**Code from CommonService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
class IP {
  ip: string;
}
export class CommonService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  strIPObservable: Observable<IP[]>;
  getClientIP(){
    return this.strIPObservable = this.http.get<IP[]>('http://api.ipify.org/');
  }

}
```

Now below code is from the **login component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Form, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonService } from '../CommonService/common.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  providers: [ CommonService ]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  LoginForm: Form;
  private router: Router;
  constructor(private ClsCommon: CommonService) {
  }
  strIP: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.strIP = this.ClsCommon.getClientIP();
  }

  OnSubmit(UserID: string, UserPwd: string) {
  }
}
```

Now below code is from **login.html**

```
<span>By Logging in, you accept ClearDesk's T&Cs.</span>
         <br>Your IP Address is => {{ strIP.ip }}
</mat-card-content>
```

Below is the **error that I'm getting Browser console**.
[image]

even after adding the CommonService to the providers array... its showing another error

[image]

Comment: Add `CommonService` in Providers array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular no provider for NameService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580083/angular-no-provider-for-nameservice)

Comment: Try the duplicate and see if it works

Comment: still i'm getting error after adding provider to the module.ts

Comment: @PrashantPimpale what you told didn't work with my code.....

Answer (score 0):

You have provided the `Injectable()` at the wrong class. You have made your class `IP` as the injectable instead of your service. Change the position of that code to:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CommonService {

// ....
```

Comment: I have generated the service like that only....    it’s already present in the code....

Comment: Well how can we know if you don't show us that? Please provide a [MCVE] to be able to correctly help you.

Comment: @AGT_82 Sorry...please have a look now.... I didnt added that because it was auto generated by the ng command...

Comment: Check answer now, you have provided the injectable at wrong class ;)

Comment: So where should I change class ip

Comment: I'm sorry, don't really understand? You can have the class where you want, I usually have a separate ts file with all models. But the point is, the injectable needs to be marked on your service.