# Storybook Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for VgimAdobeAnalyticsService

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

Hi I'm currently learning storybook and ran into this error when trying to setup.

I'm doing this in .mdx file and heres my code so far

```
import { Meta, Story } from '@storybook/addon-docs';

import { EyebrowAmountComponent } from './eyebrow-amount.component';

<Meta title="EyebrowAmount" component={EyebrowAmountComponent}/>

<Story name="Primary">
  {{
    props: {
        eyebrow: "eyebrow title",
        amount: "$12"
    },
  }}
</Story>
```

[image]

I tried googling but nothing similar came up. Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong much appreciated.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580083/angular-no-provider-for-nameservice

Answer (score -1):

Okay I figured out what the issue was. What I did wrong was I did not import all the necessary component and module to render my component in storybook.
So make sure you provide all the right declarations and imports for storybook.

Answer (score -1):

What I did wrong was unintentionally importing the Module / InjectionToken from the relative path to a project that is a package. I changed the import to the package (@...) using the public API and the error was gone.